# Variable Importance for LightGBM not working

Tags: r, error-handling, feature-selection, lightgbm

I wanted to compute the feature importance of my LGBM classification model after selecting the hyperparameters but R gives me an error and says: "Error: Model-specific variable importance scores are currently not available for this type of model."

I took the same steps for the xGBoost model and that gave me the feature importance. However, I cannot figure out how to obtain the feature importance in R successfully for the lgbm model.
My code is:

```
lgbm_tune_smote_vi <- 
  boost_tree(mtry = 13, min_n = 2, tree_depth = 2, trees=1000, learn_rate=0.01) %>%
  set_mode("classification") %>%
  set_engine("lightgbm")

lgbm_tune_wf_smote_vi <- workflow() %>%
  add_model(lgbm_tune_smote_vi) %>%
  add_recipe(lgbm_recipe_smote) 
  
set.seed(9923)
lgbm_vi_fit <- lgbm_tune_wf_smote_vi %>% fit(data = df3)
lgbm_vi_fit %>% extract_fit_parsnip() %>% vi()
```

but then I get the error: "Error: Model-specific variable importance scores are currently not available for this type of model."

It would be great if someone could help me solve the error. Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue - haven't found a solution yet either